# "ValueError: No gradients provided for any variable" when scale_diag of MultivariateNormalDiag() is a Constant

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow-probability

The following is a code snippet which, given a `state`, generates an `action` from a state-dependent distribution (`prob_policy`). Then the weights of the graph are updated according to a loss which is -1 times the probability of that action being selected. In the following example, both the mean (`mu`) and the covariance (`sigma`) of the MultivariateNormal are trainable/learned.

```
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf
import tensorflow_probability as tfp

# make the graph
state = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, (1, 2), name="state")
mu = tf.contrib.layers.fully_connected(
    inputs=state,
    num_outputs=2,
    biases_initializer=tf.ones_initializer)
sigma = tf.contrib.layers.fully_connected(
    inputs=state,
    num_outputs=2,
    biases_initializer=tf.ones_initializer)
sigma = tf.squeeze(sigma)
mu = tf.squeeze(mu)
prob_policy = tfp.distributions.MultivariateNormalDiag(loc=mu, scale_diag=sigma)
action = prob_policy.sample()
picked_action_prob = prob_policy.prob(action)
loss = -tf.log(picked_action_prob)
optimizer = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(learning_rate=0.01)
train_op = optimizer.minimize(loss)

# run the optimizer
with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
    state_input = np.expand_dims([0.,0.],0)
    _, action_loss = sess.run([train_op, loss], { state: state_input })
    print(action_loss)
```

However, when I replace this line

```
prob_policy = tfp.distributions.MultivariateNormalDiag(loc=mu, scale_diag=sigma)
```

with the following line (and comment out the lines which generate the sigma layer and squeeze it)

```
prob_policy = tfp.distributions.MultivariateNormalDiag(loc=mu, scale_diag=[1.,1.])
```

I get the following error

```
ValueError: No gradients provided for any variable, check your graph for ops that do not support gradients, between variables ["<tf.Variable 'fully_connected/weights:0' shape=(2, 2) dtype=float32_ref>", "<tf.Variable 'fully_connected/biases:0' shape=(2,) dtype=float32_ref>"] and loss Tensor("Neg:0", shape=(), dtype=float32).
```

I don't understand why this is happening. Shouldn't it still be able to take the gradient with respect to the weights in the `mu` layer? Why does making the covariance of the distribution constant suddenly make it non-differentiable?

System Details:

- Tensorflow 1.13.1
- Tensorflow Probability 0.6.0
- Python 3.6.8
- MacOS 10.13.6

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an issue caused by some caching we do inside of MVNDiag (and other subclasses of TransformedDistribution) for invertibility.

If you do a `+ 0` (as a workaround) after your .sample() the gradient will work.

Also I'd suggest using `dist.log_prob(..)` instead of `tf.log(dist.prob(..))`. Better numerics.

```py
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf
import tensorflow_probability as tfp

# make the graph
state = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, (1, 2), name="state")
mu = tf.contrib.layers.fully_connected(
    inputs=state,
    num_outputs=2,
    biases_initializer=tf.ones_initializer)
sigma = tf.contrib.layers.fully_connected(
    inputs=state,
    num_outputs=2,
    biases_initializer=tf.ones_initializer)
sigma = tf.squeeze(sigma)
mu = tf.squeeze(mu)
prob_policy = tfp.distributions.MultivariateNormalDiag(loc=mu, scale_diag=[1.,1.])
action = prob_policy.sample() + 0
loss = -prob_policy.log_prob(action)
optimizer = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(learning_rate=0.01)
train_op = optimizer.minimize(loss)

# run the optimizer
with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
    state_input = np.expand_dims([0.,0.],0)
    _, action_loss = sess.run([train_op, loss], { state: state_input })
    print(action_loss)
```

Answer (score 0):

I had to change this line

```
action = prob_policy.sample()
```

to this line

```
action = tf.stop_gradient(prob_policy.sample())
```

If anyone has an explanation for why learning the weights of the covariance makes the weights of the loc differentiable wrt the loss, but making the covariance a constant doesn't, and how this line change contrbutes to that, I would love an explanation! Thanks!